# ¿Como uso varios archivos en python?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa, y tengo un archivo, que es lo principal del programa.
Lo que ocurre es que tengo un *snippet* de código para los créditos y me gustaría ponerlo en otro archivo para no tener un solo archivo muy largo, ya que el *snippet* tiene una longitud considerable. Diganme como porfa

Comment: no uses groserías en esta plataforma

Comment: Importante que realices tus preguntas en base a [ask].

Comment: shadow: infeliz no es una groseria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes importar otros archivos del mismo directorio con `import`.
Por ejemplo, dado el siguiente directorio:

```
src/
├── main.py
└── snippets.py
```

snippets.py:

```
 A = 2
```

main.py:

```
import snippets
print snippets.A
# 2
```

También puedes importar solo parte de snippets con `from/import`

main.py:

```
from snippets import A
print A
# 2
```

Ten encuenta que para proyectos más grandes, en los que tengas varias carpetas, deberás además añadir a cada carpeta del código del proyecto un archivo `__init__.py`, para que python sepa que debe tratar esa carpeta como un paquete de código. Para acceder a otro directorio debes usar en el import la ruta con .

```
src/
├── snippets/
│   ├── snippet1.py
│   ├── snippet2.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── main.py
└── __init__.py
```

snippet1.py:

```
 A = 2
```

main.py:

```
from snippets import snippet1
print snippet1.A
# 2
```

O bien:

main.py:

```
from snippets.snippet1 import A
print A
# 2
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda